# why does this code gives runtime error?

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> intersection(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        sort(nums1.begin(),nums1.end());
        sort(nums2.begin(),nums2.end());
        vector<int> a;
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        while(i<nums1.size()&&j<nums2.size())
        {
            if(nums1[i]>nums2[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
            else if(nums1[i]<nums2[j])
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(a.empty() || a.back() != nums1[i])
                {
                    a[k]=nums1[i];
                }
                i++;
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.  You're being downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: It's not clear, but you don't seem to be declaring the vector type. vector is a template, and therefore needs a type to hold in the container vector <T>. E.g vector <double>. Are you sure this is a run time error? Does the code complie?

Comment: replace `a[k]` with `a.at(k)`.  You will learn the beauty of using `at()` to solve your own issue with out-of-bounds access (instead of getting a segmentation fault or crash).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Now that his code is formatted, he'll keep getting downvoted to oblivion for not using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is declared a an empty vector so you cannot access elements of `a` unless there are any elements in `a`.
You want

```
  a.push_back(nums[i]);
```

instead of

```
  a[k] = nums1[i]; //a is declared as empty vector so you have to push elements to it.
```

OR

you can do

```
vector<int> a(num1.size());
```

instead of

```
vector<int> a;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your accessing of vector by a[k].

vector a being an empty vector can't be accessed with a[k].

You need to use **a.push_back(nums[i]);**

or

declare vector of some size like vector a(10);
and then access it with a[k].